# Special characters rendering off place in Firefox

Tags: css, google-font-api, google-fonts

I’m building a website using Google Fonts. In particular I’m using “Archivo Black”.

The font supports special characters such as accents and others, however in Firefox those accents are rending in a really weird position… and in Chrome they look perfectly fine.

I’ve been looking all around but I don’t think there is a way to control the position of such elements via CSS, so I really don’t understand why this might be happening.

In the images below I'm just highlighting one instance when this is happening but if you look closer you'll see it's a consistent issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I noticed this problem too when i copied text from word or other applications. It seemed to have some strange formating. When i removed the letter manually and typed it again (right into the code or CMS system) it looked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are using the ['COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT' (U+0301)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm)  along with the `U` character instead of the ['LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE' (U+00FA)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00FA/index.htm) `Ú`.

The former character set is not in your font so the browser has to use an other system font, which is why it may not render correctly. You can check this in the font panel of your dev-tools.
However, your font does have the `Ú` character, so if you fix it in your markup, you should be good in all browsers.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black');
body{
  font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div>MU&#x301;SICA (U +  &#x301; )</div>

<div>MÚSICA (Ú)</div>
```